# Change span font color and background cover when hovering div

Tags: html, css

I have found several variations on this question, but I'm stumped.  I'm trying to create changes in my span when I hover over my div.

I am trying to make the black background turn white, and the font turn black when I hover over the div.  The changes, I think, are reflected in the span.

But so far I have this: http://nybg.beta.libguides.com/c.php?g=566117

All I can think is that I am overwriting something unintentionally in the code I grabbed via SnappySnippet.  I am new to this, so pardon my ignorance!

I have made a fiddle here with the css and html that I am using, but it's not displaying properly: https://jsfiddle.net/emj042/ke6fL5mz/

```css
.departments img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
#DIV_1 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 0px 10px 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  perspective-origin: 143.297px 81px;
  transform-origin: 143.297px 81px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font: normal normal normal normal 16px / 16px"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px -4px 24px 28.3125px;
}
/*#DIV_1*/

#SPAN_1 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 142.297px 16.5px;
  transform-origin: 142.297px 16.5px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-right: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-left: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal bold normal 12px / normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  padding: 6px 6px;
}
/*#SPAN_1*/

#SPAN_1:after {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  content: '▶';
  display: block;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 11px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 5.5px 10px;
  transform-origin: 5.5px 10px;
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal bold normal 15px / normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}
/*#SPAN_1:after*/

#SPAN_1:hover {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="departments">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <div id="DIV_1">
      <a href="http://adulted.nybg.org:8080/cart65/jsp/index.jsp?categoryId=10093">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.nybg.org/adulted/icon/BOTANICAL-ART-Longleaf-Pine_289x162.jpg" /> <span id="SPAN_1">Botanical Art &amp; Illustration</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want the hover CSS rule to be on the containing element, `#DIV1`, so that the change will happen regardless of where you hover(not just when you hover the caption). You also had your CSS in the wrong pane in your fiddle.

```
#DIV_1:hover #SPAN_1 {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

To solve for the image `opacity` issue when hovering the `span` simply change your `opacity` rule to the following:

```
#DIV_1:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ke6fL5mz/2/)

Comment: Ah!  Thank you so much!  And yeesh what a way to make a first post.  :)  Again, thanks so much.

Comment: It's actually a pretty good post for your first post, I have seen far worse, trust me haha. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Here is one more question for you.  Now when I hover over the span, the opacity for the image disappears.  Should I be putting that into the #DIV_1 element as well?

Comment: And, again, thanks!  For the welcome and for the help.

Comment: Updated my answer and the JSFiddle link.

Comment: Ah!  That's wonderful!  Thank you so much.  I've just reviewed it so that I understand the change.  Makes logical sense, thank you for showing me how to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your fiddle:  You put the CSS code into the Javascript field of the fiddle, which is why it doesn't work.

I changed it, added `color: black` to the hover rule and modified the selector of the hover rule:

https://jsfiddle.net/ah49w525/2/